How to pass a function in main as a widget?
So i have the main widget where i navigate in LogIn page ,the concept - scenario is that after the login i save the user credentials for future use , im trying to avoid rendering the login page again so i want this to be automated in the main and not in the login page anymore .
My code :
main :
void main() async {
  try {
    WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

    //Load .env Variables
    await dotenv.load();

  } catch (error) {
  }
  runApp(MyApp());
}


Widget? initialWidget;

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  
    load_Saved_Credentials(context).then((credentialsSaved) {
      setState(() {
        initialWidget = credentialsSaved ? null : LogIn();
      });
    });
  }
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    .......................................
    ......................................
  return MultiProvider(
              providers: [
                //Providers
                ChangeNotifierProvider<Coins_And_Gems_State>(
                  create: (context) => Coins_And_Gems_State(),
                ),
                ChangeNotifierProvider<UserState>(
                  create: (context) => UserState(),
                ),
                ChangeNotifierProvider<ImageState>(
                  create: (context) => ImageState(),
                ),
              ],
              child: MaterialApp(
                supportedLocales: localization.supportedLocales,
                localizationsDelegates: localization.localizationsDelegates,
                home: initialWidget,
                onGenerateRoute: AppRoutes.generateRoute,
    .......................................
    ......................................


Here i load the user credentials :
Future<bool> load_Saved_Credentials(BuildContext context) async {
  String? username = await storage.read(key: 'username');
  String? password = await storage.read(key: 'password');
  if (username != null &&
      password != null &&
      username.isNotEmpty &&
      password.isNotEmpty) {
    login(username, password, context);
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}

and the Login Controller :
Future<void> login(
    String emailController, String passwordController, context) async {

   Provider.of<UserState>(context, listen: false).setUserId(
            email: email,
            username: username);

        //Navigate into Home screen
        Navigator.pushNamed(context, AppRoutes.home);

}


The problem is that its working BUT the providers is not setting the correct values , in fact its not getting any values ,i must take for example the user email and when i enter my app its null .
Error logs :
Performing hot restart...                                            
   
Restarted application in 3,963ms.
D/EGL_emulation(15824): app_time_stats: avg=339.59ms min=5.65ms max=8117.29ms count=26
E/flutter (15824): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: Error: Could not find the correct Provider<UserState> above this MyApp Widget
E/flutter (15824):
E/flutter (15824): This happens because you used a `BuildContext` that does not include the provider
E/flutter (15824): of your choice. There are a few common scenarios: 
E/flutter (15824):
E/flutter (15824): - You added a new provider in your `main.dart` and performed a hot-reload.
E/flutter (15824):   To fix, perform a hot-restart.
E/flutter (15824):
E/flutter (15824): - The provider you are trying to read is in a different route.
E/flutter (15824):
E/flutter (15824):   Providers are "scoped". So if you insert of provider inside a route, then
E/flutter (15824):   other routes will not be able to access that provider.
E/flutter (15824):
E/flutter (15824): - You used a `BuildContext` that is an ancestor of the provider you are trying to read.
E/flutter (15824):
E/flutter (15824):   Make sure that MyApp is under your MultiProvider/Provider<UserState>.
E/flutter (15824):   This usually happens when you are creating a provider and trying to read it immediately.
E/flutter (15824):
E/flutter (15824):   For example, instead of:
E/flutter (15824): 
E/flutter (15824):   ```
E/flutter (15824):   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
E/flutter (15824):     return Provider<Example>(
E/flutter (15824):       create: (_) => Example(),
E/flutter (15824):       // Will throw a ProviderNotFoundError, because `context` is associated
E/flutter (15824):       // to the widget that is the parent of `Provider<Example>`
E/flutter (15824):       child: Text(context.watch<Example>().toString()),
E/flutter (15824):     );
E/flutter (15824):   }
E/flutter (15824):   ```
E/flutter (15824):
E/flutter (15824):   consider using `builder` like so:
E/flutter (15824):
E/flutter (15824):   ```
E/flutter (15824):   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
E/flutter (15824):     return Provider<Example>(
E/flutter (15824):       create: (_) => Example(),
E/flutter (15824):       // we use `builder` to obtain a new `BuildContext` that has access to the provider
E/flutter (15824):       builder: (context, child) {
E/flutter (15824):         // No longer throws
E/flutter (15824):         return Text(context.watch<Example>().toString());
E/flutter (15824):       }
E/flutter (15824):     );
E/flutter (15824):   }
E/flutter (15824):   ```
E/flutter (15824):
E/flutter (15824): If none of these solutions work, consider asking for help on StackOverflow:
E/flutter (15824): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flutter
E/flutter (15824):
E/flutter (15824): #0      Provider._inheritedElementOf (package:provider/src/provider.dart:343:7)
E/flutter (15824): #1      Provider.of (package:provider/src/provider.dart:293:30)
E/flutter (15824): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (15824): 
D/EGL_emulation(15824): 


Any ideas?
Thanks .

load_Saved_Credentials(context).then in initState() method, from where did you get that context, the exception says you are using a context above the provided State Manager, make sure you are passing a Widget's context that is lower than your provider in widget tree.

I manage to fix the issue by making a new landing page widget with a circular progress indicator and call the functions from there .
I dont know for some reason it worked but the provider had issues. I was first setting the provider and then called the navigate route to home page but it did not worked .
Now its working with the new widget landing page.
I will post the answer below for future solution for others.

I manage to fix it by creating a new widget called Landing page , there i put a circular indicator for some seconds . If the load_Saved_Credentials(context) does not trigger the navigation to home page - screen then it will go to Login screen again . If it return false it will again go to Login screen .
My guess is that something went wrong with the widget tree priority and the provider as A-E metion too .
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Landing_Page extends StatefulWidget {
  const Landing_Page({super.key});

  @override
  _Landing_PageState createState() => _Landing_PageState();
}

class _Landing_PageState extends State<Landing_Page>{
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    load_Saved_Credentials(context);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder<bool>(
        future: Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2), () => true),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          } else {
            if (snapshot.data == true) {
              return LogIn();
            } else {
              return LogIn();
            }
          }
        });
  }
}

